# How to filter inside of map in redux reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I'm having trouble of deleting the string inside of array in my redux. I did some trial and error on console and I am successfully filtering the the array and removing the string. but once I dispatch my action creator and send the payload and filter It doesn't work.

here's the sample data. what I was trying to do is remove or filter out the data inside of task array.

```
password: "$2b$12$Hb5AAO/pDSt2SpGpGUnPQOGuUAcTWjSSf.GjUxQ.LRBI6u2dRTGby"
task: (5) ["asd", "sd", "qwe", "zxc", "cvb"]
time: "2021-08-22T13:26:19.337Z"
username: "admin"
__v: 0
_id: "6122507bc5867440784a9421"
```

here's my dispatch.

```
const deleteRequest = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch(removeTask(postdata.id,postdata.post));
}
```

here's my action creator using by redux-thunk.

```
export const removeTask = (id,post) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        await api.deleteTask(id,post);
        dispatch({ type: 'DELETE', payload: post });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

here's my reducer on redux where I'm trying to filter out the payload I will sent but it doesn't work so please check it.

```
case 'DELETE':
     return {
        post: state.post.map(data => data.task.filter((post) => post !== action.payload))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your state.post is an object so you don't need mapping. your need filtering the only task array.
can you try this?

```
case 'DELETE':
 return {
    ...state,
    post: state.post.task.filter((post) => post !== action.payload)
}
```